# Does ILASM work with Mixed Mode Application?

Tags: ilasm, ildasm

I am trying to modify a method in a third-party dll

1. Use ILDASM to generate IL
2. Modify IL method
3. Use ILASM to generate DLL (FAILURE)

I found the reason due to this error is the third-party dll contains unmanaged code.
Is there any way that I can succeed?

Comment: Dotfuscator does this successfully. You might look in to how they do it.